# Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 or higher

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I want to be able to use the async keyword but I want my typescript to compile into es5 code so that my code can run in the average persons browser. I get this error when I try to use `async` in visual studio code.

> Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 or
>   higher.

I thought that targeting `es6` means that the output javascript from compiling the typescript will be `es6`, and `es6` doesn't work on most browsers yet?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir":"js/app/",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "app/test"
  ]
}
```

I was wondering if the `lib` field might make it work because it says `"es2015"` but it doesn't.

I'm also thinking maybe the `core-js` shim makes `async` available but I only include that shim in my `index.html` like this:

`<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>`

So I don't think it's making `async` available at compile time. Is there a better way to import core-js?

How do I make `async` usable but also not have my code be unable to run on most browsers?

Comment: This should work in [Typescript 2.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-downlevel-async-functions), coming real soon now...

Comment: `core-js` is polyfill. `async` with `es6` target relies on generators. They can't be polyfilled. Generally Babel should be used  in conjunction with TS to transpile them to ES5. As said, `async` for `es5` target is available in 2.1 dev version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ECMAScript6` is supported in most major browsers.

As stated in the comments on this answer by @loganfsmyth,

> Just keep in mind that "most major browsers" could still only cover a
>   tiny percentage of your user base.

[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla)

[Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4633745457938432)

[From Safari's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html),

> ES6 The ECMAScript 2015 standard, also known as ES6, is completely
>   supported, bringing this major JavaScript evolution to Safari on macOS
>   and iOS.

You are going to have to change,

```
"target": "es5",
```

To

```
"target": "es6",
```

> TypeScript 1.7 async/await support in ES6 targets (Node v4+)
>   TypeScript now supports asynchronous functions for engines that have
>   native support for ES6 generators, e.g. Node v4 and above.
>   Asynchronous functions are prefixed with the async keyword; await
>   suspends the execution until an asynchronous function return promise
>   is fulfilled and unwraps the value from the Promise returned.

Comment: Just keep in mind that "most major browsers" could still only cover a tiny percentage of your userbase.